# How to get full head image from haar cascade

Tags: python, opencv, haar-classifier

i used the following code to capture a face using Haar cascade classifier but  still have not get full head image

```
from imutils.video import WebcamVideoStream
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime
from imutils.video import FPS
import cv2
cascadePath = "/home/pi/opencv-3.3.0/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/pi/opencv-3.3.0/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml')
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath);

fn = input('Enter your Folder name: ')
os.system("mkdir "+fn)

vs = WebcamVideoStream(src=0).start()

while 1:
    time.sleep(0.05)
    frame = vs.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 6)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.imwrite(fn+"/"+ datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f") + ".jpg", gray[y:y+h+30,x:x+w+20])
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to capture the head also you need to **decrease** the initial point where you start cropping the face.

In your code you have used `gray[y:y+h+30,x:x+w+20]`.

- `y` takes into account the height of the cropped face. This is where you need to decrease the initial cropping point.
- `x` denotes the width of the face which you do not need to change.

Conclusion: Change it to `gray[y-20:y+h, x:x+w]` in line 22 within `cv2.imwrite()`.